# How to set word Limit in meta Description

Tags: php, metadata, meta-tags

I am new to PHP language, downloaded 'ClassifiedAdLister' for education purposes. My problem is with the meta description limit, I want my meta description character limit 160 instead of full description posted in the Description field.

Kindly visit here for further reference
http://sujoonbiswas.epizy.com/classi/

**Source Code**
view-source:http://sujoonbiswas.epizy.com/classi/listing-hi-this-is-0.html

**Current Code**

```
<meta name="description" content="This My First Post Please Read My Post Care Fully, This Is SEO Friendly Template


One
Two
Three


Sultan Shah - SEO Guru
Hello Friwnds How Are You
          
  
    
      
        Firstname
        Lastname
        Email
      
    
    
      
        John
        Doe
        john@example.com
      
      
        Mary
        Moe
        mary@example.com
      
      
        July
        Dooley
        july@example.com
      
    
  "/>
```

**Looking For**

```
<meta name="description" content="This My First Post Please Read My Post Care Fully, This Is SEO Friendly Template"/>
```

**Character Limit 160**

2- Also Looking For Complete Title in URL Instead of Three Words.

**Current URL**
http://sujoonbiswas.epizy.com/classi/listing-hi-this-is-0.html

**Looking For**
http://sujoonbiswas.epizy.com/classi/listing-hi-this-is-sultan-shah-your-seo-guru-0.html

You can find Original Script here
https://www.netartmedia.net/adlister

Regards

Comment: You can use the PHP function substr to obtain the 160 characters that you need.

$meta_description=substr('Your long text here.....',0,160);

<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta_description; ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr function of php to limit the string.

```
$your_string = "A long String";
$start = 0 //starting character
$length = 50 //Desired length
$limited_string = substr($your_string,$start,$length);
```

For more info https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Thanks Mr. Gopal Kohli.